# Freeswitch errors when trying to start

Tags: freeswitch

I am having issues with a newfies dialer. The whole server was working all day and when i rebooted the server i was no longer able to get into `fs_cli`. 
I got this error:

```
[ERROR] fs_cli.c:1610 main() Error Connecting [Socket Connection Error] Usage: /usr/local/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli [-H <host>] [-P <port>] [-p <secret>] [-d <level>] [-x command] [-t <timeout_ms>] [profile]
```

I found freeswitch was not even running. I tried restarting freeswitch with no luck.

i also tried to initialize freeswitch again to see if maybe there was a setting that got screwed up and i received this error

```
root@20151028-newfies-bak-16gb-nyc3-01:~# cd /usr/local/freeswitch/bin
root@20151028-newfies-bak-16gb-nyc3-01:/usr/local/freeswitch/bin# ./freeswitch
2016-10-06 21:16:04.928227 [INFO] switch_event.c:685 Activate Eventing Engine.
2016-10-06 21:16:04.938975 [WARNING] switch_event.c:656 Create additional event dispatch thread 0
2016-10-06 21:16:04.952491 [ERR] switch_xml.c:1385 Couldn't open /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/../sip_profiles/external-ipv6/*.xml (No such file or directory)
Cannot Initialize [[error near line 2617]: unexpected closing tag </gateway>]
```

I went into the file where that error was to see if it would fix the issue but after i commented out the issue and rebooted the server again, the comments disappeared and getting same issue. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I found out that line 2617 correlated to sip_ext.xml file and i had forgotten a few / at the end of a couple params towards the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you introduced an error in your gateway configuration which prevent FreeSWITCH to restart normally. I would advice to review the last changes you made in your SIP profiles and ensure they are well-formed XML